# Inline slide effect using JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slide

I am trying to hide an alert which is displayed inline using the [slide](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/) function. It is displayed inline but the sliding doesn't happen inline like I intend it to happen. How can I make the sliding happen inline?

The following is the snippet with current code

```js
$("#testDiv2").show();

$("#testDiv2").on('click', function () {
$("#testDiv2").hide('slide',{direction: 'left'}, 6000);
});

$(function() {
    if ($("#testDiv2").is(':visible')) 
     $("#testDiv2").css('display','inline-block'); 
});
```

```css
#test,#testDiv,#testDiv2 { 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
A
<div id="testDiv2">
    <div id="testDiv" class="alert alert-success">Click to close</div>
</div>
B
</div>
```

Related posts:

- I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10016488/2246380) post which suggests to change to `inline-block`
  which doesn't solve the issue.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15129952/2246380) self answered question is
  similar to mine but it is about displaying the next one inline not
  about the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out that this piece of code will fix the inline problem for you, but there are still some layout issues. I'm working on it.

```
#test > div.ui-effects-wrapper {
   display: inline-block !important;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
$("#testDiv2").show();

$("#testDiv2").on('click', function() {
  $("#testDiv2").hide('slide', {
    direction: 'left'
  }, 6000);
});

$(function() {
  if ($("#testDiv2").is(':visible'))
    $("#testDiv2").css('display', 'inline-block');
});
```

```css
#test,
#testDiv,
#testDiv2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
#test > div.ui-effects-wrapper {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  A
  <div id="testDiv2">
    <div id="testDiv" class="alert alert-success">Click to close</div>
  </div>
  B
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please what `ui-effects-wrapper` is?

Comment: Making `ui-effects-wrapper` `inline` instead of `inline-block` makes it better but the sliding effect goes over A which is not I want it to do.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `jquery-ui` but it seems like the `ui-effects-wrapper` (a wrapper for the sliding element) is being created during the animation process.

Comment: that wrapper is a real pain in the a.. :|

Comment: True. I have been trying too.